# UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext Problem

Tags: objective-c, core-graphics, quartz-graphics, quartz-2d

I have a problem drawing objects passing this graphic context

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
```

Here is the code I use to draw

```
- (void) draw: (CGContextRef) gc
{       
    CGFloat black[4] = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}; // R G B + Alpha
    CGPoint p [2];
    p[0].x = xStart ;
    p[0].y = yStart ;
    p[1].x = xEnd ;
    p[1].y = yEnd ;
    CGContextSetStrokeColor(gc, black); //Definie la couleur
    CGContextStrokeLineSegments(gc, p, 2 ) ;
}
```

Some object draw, other don't (very strange) and in the console I read:

```
    Thu Mar 24 21:53:59 MacBook-Air-di-Michele-Giarratana.local IVBricker[381] <Error>: CGContextDrawImage: invalid context 0x0
Thu Mar 24 21:53:59 MacBook-Air-di-Michele-Giarratana.local IVBricker[381] <Error>: CGContextSetStrokeColor: invalid context 0x0
Thu Mar 24 21:53:59 MacBook-Air-di-Michele-Giarratana.local IVBricker[381] <Error>: CGContextStrokeLineSegments: invalid context 0x0
Thu Mar 24 21:53:59 MacBook-Air-di-Michele-Giarratana.local IVBricker[381] <Error>: CGContextSetStrokeColor: invalid context 0x0
Thu Mar 24 21:53:59 MacBook-Air-di-Michele-Giarratana.local IVBricker[381] <Error>: CGContextStrokeLineSegments: invalid context 0x0
Thu Mar 24 21:53:59 MacBook-Air-di-Michele-Giarratana.local IVBricker[381] <Error>: CGContextSetStrokeColor: invalid context 0x0
Thu Mar 24 21:53:59 MacBook-Air-di-Michele-Giarratana.local IVBricker[381] <Error>: CGContextStrokeLineSegments: invalid context 0x0
Thu Mar 24 21:53:59 MacBook-Air-di-Michele-Giarratana.local IVBricker[381] <Error>: CGContextSetStrokeColor: invalid context 0x0
Thu Mar 24 21:53:59 MacBook-Air-di-Michele-Giarratana.local IVBricker[381] <Error>: CGContextStrokeLineSegments: invalid context 0x0
Thu Mar 24 21:53:59 MacBook-Air-di-Michele-Giarratana.local IVBricker[381] <Error>: CGContextSetStrokeColor: invalid context 0x0
Thu Mar 24 21:53:59 MacBook-Air-di-Michele-Giarratana.local IVBricker[381] <Error>: CGContextStrokeLineSegments: invalid context 0x0
```

Comment: Where exactly (in what case) are you calling the draw method? Show the code where you are calling draw with the context. Also, are you calling this on the main thread or a detached one?

Comment: A agree with @Kalle -- the first thing to check is if you're calling `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext` on the main thread. I'm willing to bet you're not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I can't speak to the invalid content errors because we'd need to see the rest of the code but it looks like the colour space could be incorrect (it's not RGB by default). Add this before you call stroke:

```
CGContextSetStrokeColorSpace(gc, CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB());
```

Comment: This will create a leak. You should do something like `CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();CGContextSetStrokeColorSpace(gc, colorSpace);CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);`